# Python pip install requirements.txt -requirements to build wheel did not run successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt

I'm trying to install a python package I created on other computers for others to use. When they go to install the required dependencies with `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get the following:

```
C:\Users\user1\my_program>pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting async-generator==1.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached async_generator-1.10-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting attrs==21.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached backports.entry_points_selectable-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
Collecting certifi==2021.10.8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting cffi==1.15.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached cffi-1.15.0.tar.gz (484 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
 
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vndhtpl4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vndhtpl4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vndhtpl4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vndhtpl4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 126, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 105, in uses_msvc
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vndhtpl4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 223, in try_compile
          self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vndhtpl4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 128, in _compile
          self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vndhtpl4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 343, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vndhtpl4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vndhtpl4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 233, in msvc14_get_vc_env
          return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vndhtpl4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 190, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
          raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]
 
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
 
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
 
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I'm not super familiar with pip aside from very basic things. Thank you for your help!

Comment: ok, did you try to address what the error message is telling you: `distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`?